# Config ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm using this vscode extension - [ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets).

Does anyone know how to config the snippets come with this extension?

Comment: if the language setting of the file matches that of the snippets file they should be available (javascript, typescript, javascriptreact, typescriptreact)

Comment: https://imgur.com/kaOMwDA

the snippets files are empty. Seems like the extension is hide the snippets somewhere...

Comment: the snippet file is defined IN the extension. Just go to the extension page and try one of the shown snippets in a JavaScript file

Comment: By "defined IN the extension", does it mean we cannot change the snippets?

Comment: you can change the snippets in the extension but you lose changes the next extension update, just make a copy of the snippet in a user snippet file and give it a different prefix

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 10, I did this:

- Went to

> C:\Users\{username}\.vscode\extensions\dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets-4.4.3\lib\snippets

- Edited the

> generated.json

- Saved it
- Restarted VS Code

Now, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no direct way to edit the es7 snippets from VS Code.

You can go to your file manager → press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> (to view hidden files) → .vscode → extensions → dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets-x.x.x → snippets → snippets.json

Open snippets.json in any text editor and customize snippets